# Make a PL/SQL stored procedure roll back all changes when an exception occurs?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, transactions, rollback

I have a procedure that makes a number of updates to different tables. I want all of the changes to be rolled back should any error occur anywhere in the procedure. Therefore I utilized this structure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE foo (x NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
  -- Do some inserts here.
  INSERT INTO bar VALUES (x);
  -- Sometimes there might be an error.
  IF x = 3 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Wooops...');
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    --Rollback all the changes and then raise the error again.
    ROLLBACK;
    RAISE;
END foo;
```

The problem is that this rolls back everything that has been done since the last commit, not just the changes made by the procedure. For instance, this will insert 4 and 5, but 1 and 2 will be rolled back:

```sql
BEGIN
  FOR x IN 1..5 LOOP
    BEGIN
      foo(x);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        NULL;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

How can I make the procedure roll back only the changes the procedure did during this call? I guess I should use transactions somehow, but I am not sure how to set it up.

Please note that I want to fix this in the code for the procedure, and not in the code that calls it.

Comment: see oracle savepoint http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10001.htm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Oracle you can use `SAVEPOINTS`. It would be this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo (x NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
  SAVEPOINT update_bar;

  -- Do some inserts here.
  INSERT INTO bar VALUES (x);
  -- Sometimes there might be an error.
  IF x = 3 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Wooops...');
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    -- Rollback everything which was made after `SAVEPOINT update_bar`
    ROLLBACK TO update_bar;
    RAISE;
END foo;
```

Comment: Do you also need to add a COMMIT ?

Comment: If you like to commit yes

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Will there be any kind of problem since there will be a savepoint created with the same time everytime the procedure is called? Or do Oracle forget about the savepoint once the procedure is done?

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it and it inserts 1, 2, 4, 5 just like it should. Since I don't do a commit between procedure calls in the loop, I guess it just roll back to the newest savepoint named `update_bar`.